# Make diagonal line that can be supported in IE

Tags: css

I am trying to make a diagonal line for the navbar, until now i have used some clip-path but I still have problems on responsive in IE the older versions, so is there any other way with pure css that I can use it ?

This is what I am using now :

```
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 93% 0, 86% 100%, 0% 100%);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: left;
      height: inherit;
      @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
      height: auto;
      }
    }
```

[diagonal line with clip-path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RUnr.png)

I get this one but again that does not solve the problem in IE older version starting from Edge v44.18362.449.0 and lower

Comment: Use an image as fallback.

Comment: @cloned that is nice trick thanks, but still I think it would be better If there is some solution using pure css

Comment: It's not a trick. The solution is to use an image because of browsers don't understand this. You can use svg to have a clearer, better scaling edge.

Comment: Are you using IE1-8?

Comment: @RingGamesCompany I am using the version I have specified in the question

Comment: @cloned I wiil have a try with svg, but what is going to happen on responsive ?

Comment: Whatever you define will happen. You can style svg with mediaqueries, so it's up to you what happens.